# Form is closing on message box button click

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I am facing a strange problem, I am showing a message box with yes|no buttons, but whenever any of the button on message box is clicked it closes the form also.

I thought it is something related to my code so I tried only this much code on my button click

```
if(MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this category?", "Delete Category",
                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                    MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) 
                    == DialogResult.Yes)
 {
     // doing nothing just to check
 }
```

But that is also closing the form.

I tried putting button in different places, tried adding different buttons etc but nothing is working.

Is there anything I can try or could be the reason?

Comment: One reason could be that the button is set as the form's AcceptButton or CancelButton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `DialogResult` property of the button you use to show the message dialog. It must be set to `DialogResult.None`.

And as VahidND suggested in his comment, ensure that the button is not set as its parent form `AcceptButton` or `CancelButton`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dmitry. Yes it was set to DialogResult.Cancel. It works perfectly now :)

Comment: You're very welcome! I remember once being stuck with the same problem myself.